# Count occurrences by group and add a column of percentages in python

Tags: python, pandas

**My problem:** Given a data frame I want to count occurrences of "is_bot" by "processed" as a grouping variable and then calculate the percentages using "is_bot" as the grouping variable.

**My data:** My data looks like this:

```
    is_bot  processed
0   No Bot  2
1   self_declared   3
2   self_declared   1
3   No Bot  3
4   No Bot  2
5   No Bot  1
6   No Bot  3
7   No Bot  1
8   No Bot  1
9   No Bot  2
```

**So far:** I have successfully calculated the occurrences. Then I managed to calculate the percentages. But I can't manage to do it within the same data frame.

```
foo = df.groupby(["processed", "is_bot"]).size()
foo

processed  is_bot       
1          No Bot           3
           self_declared    1
2          No Bot           3
3          No Bot           2
           self_declared    1
dtype: int64

foo.groupby("is_bot").transform(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum())

processed  is_bot       
1          No Bot           37.5
           self_declared    50.0
2          No Bot           37.5
3          No Bot           25.0
           self_declared    50.0
dtype: float64
```

**My Data:** This is the dict for my raw data:

```
df = {'is_bot': {0: 'No Bot', 1: 'self_declared', 2: 'self_declared', 3: 'No Bot', 4: 'No Bot', 5: 'No Bot', 6: 'No Bot', 7: 'No Bot', 8: 'No Bot', 9: 'No Bot'}, 'processed': {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 3, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 2}}
```

**Extra:** I am able to do it in `R` using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(processed) %>% 
  count(is_bot) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(is_bot) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n/sum(n)*100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need grouping by both columns first, get counts and then aggregate again but only one column. Here are possible alterative solutions:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["processed", "is_bot"])
         .size()
         .div(df['is_bot'].value_counts(), level=1)
         .mul(100))
print (df1)
```

Or join both:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["processed", "is_bot"]).size()
         .groupby("is_bot").transform(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum()))
```

Or use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize` parameter, but it count also not match values like `0`, so need replace them and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df['processed'], df['is_bot'], normalize=1)
         .replace(0, np.nan)
         .stack()
         .mul(100))
print (df1)
processed  is_bot       
1          No Bot           37.5
           self_declared    50.0
2          No Bot           37.5
3          No Bot           25.0
           self_declared    50.0
dtype: float64
```

For both columns use:

```
s = df.groupby(["processed", "is_bot"]).size()
s1 = s.groupby("is_bot").transform(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum())

df2 = pd.concat([s, s1], axis=1, keys=('count','perc'))
```

Or:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(["processed", "is_bot"])
         .size()
         .to_frame('count')
         .assign(perc = lambda x: x.groupby("is_bot").transform(lambda x: 100*x/x.sum())))

print (df2)
                         count  perc
processed is_bot                    
1         No Bot             3  37.5
          self_declared      1  50.0
2         No Bot             3  37.5
3         No Bot             2  25.0
          self_declared      1  50.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer the problem is that I want both columns in the data frame one for the counts and the other with the percentages!

Comment: @TitoSanz - maybe last paragraph is what need. Added to answer.